# Angular 2 : filter multiple fields with Pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

i have table with two column codeproduct, nmproduct. i have been success if only filter one field. this is my code :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'productFilter'
})

export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: IProduct[], args: string[]): IProduct[] {
    let filter: string = args[0] ? args[0].toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
    return filter ? value.filter((product: IProduct) =>
        product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1) :   value;
}
}
```

how to filter with multiple fields codeproduct or nmproduct? thank you

Answer (score 4):

Hard to understand your question.. But maybe this will help:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'productFilter'
})

export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: IProduct[], filter: string): IProduct[] {
      filter = filter ? filter.toLocaleLowerCase() : '';
      return filter && value ?
        value.filter(product =>
           (product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1) ||
           (product.??npmName??.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1)
        ) :
        value;
   }
}
```